Implementing siteCode-based translations w/Ng17(i18n) Storybook
I'm implementing internationalization (i18n) in an Angular 17 project using the approach outlined in the Angular documentation for merging translations. My goal is to have a single application that can be translated based on a siteCode, with translations stored in .properties files.
While this approach works for the main application, I'm encountering issues integrating it with Storybook. The isolated environment of Storybook is making it challenging to set up the global TranslationService, and I'm unsure how to handle Angular 17's new control flow syntax in this context.

Created a custom TranslationService to load and parse .properties files based on siteCode:

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TranslationService {
  use(siteCode: string) {
    ....
  }
}


Implemented a TranslatePipe for use in templates:

@Pipe({
  name: 'translate',
  pure: false
})
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  ....
}

Questions

How can I effectively integrate this siteCode-based translation approach with Storybook in an Angular 17 project?
What's the best way to handle Angular 17's new control flow syntax within Storybook stories when dealing with translations?
Are there any recommended patterns for managing different translations for various siteCodes within Storybook stories?

Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
